# Is there name to the following sequence: $c_n = c_1c_2...c_{n-1} + 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I just saw the sequence $c_n = c_0c_1c_2...c_{n-1} + 1$ and is thinking whether sequence $(c_n)$ has some name.

Add: What if $c_0 \neq 2$?

Comment: is needed some $c_0$ or $c_1$ value.

Comment: Assuming a default of either 0 or 1, this is https://oeis.org/A129871 - and see also https://oeis.org/A000058 (which is the same sequence without the 1' at the head of it).

Comment: It is Sylvester's sequence.

Comment: Well, if $c_0=1$, then it's (except for leading term) Sylvester's sequence again. And same with $c_0=0$, as Steven says above. Similarly if you pick a term that appears later in Sylvester's sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $c_0=2$ it is [Sylvester's sequence](http://oeis.org/A000058), given in OEIS as A000058, also known as the Euclid numbers from the proof of an infinite number of primes.